# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/book_screen } cannot be found
```

**Navroot host:**

```
animatedCompose("${Graph.BOOK}/{id}",
arguments = listOf(
    navArgument("id"){
        type = NavType.LongType
        defaultValue = -1
    }
)
    ){
    val id = it.arguments?.getInt("id") ?: -1
    val actionText = if(id != -1) "Save" else "Add"
    val title = if(id != -1) "Edit Book" else "Add New Book"
    BookScreen(navHostController, title=title, actionText=actionText)
}
```

**From within another screen:**

```
 Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                rootNavHostController.navigate(Graph.BOOK)
            }) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add,null)
            }
        }
```

I assume, that you can make the `{id}` optional as an argument. But, not sure of why things don't work at this moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved it by doing this:**

```
animatedCompose("${Graph.BOOK}/?id={id}",
  arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("id"){
                type = NavType.IntType
                defaultValue = -1
            }
        ){}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe somebody is still looking for this answer:
I had this problem because sent a JSON to another screen and it contained "/", so I just replaced it like this:

```
   navController.navigate(
                        Screen.DetailScreen.withArgs(
                            Gson()
                                .toJson(itemSkin)
                                .toString()
                                .replace("/", "$$$")
                        )
                    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was causing the problem for me, as I was passing a Uri which also contained "/" symbols!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants an easy solution, **without using** **Gson** or something. Today I was working on an application, and one of the requirements was to send an image link to another screen.

The Url was something like this `https://westandwithpalastine.com/gaza/`.
The URL was a string, But when I sent it to the other screen using **Parcelable**, it assumed it was "**( Uri )**" so I got this error message

```
error message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/display_photo/https://via.placeholder.com/600/dc17bf } cannot be found in the navigation graph ComposeNavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0x845f817c) route=profile} at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1815) at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:2221) at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:2216)
```

**So what was the solution?**

With the **encoded Url**, It worked perfectly, and you can use it something like this

```
fun NavController.navigateToImageScreen(
    imageUrl: String,
) {
    val encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(imageUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
    navigate("${Screen.Image.route}/$encodedUrl")
}
```

Now it will work without any problems. If you want to know how the route function will be, here's the full code.

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.imageRoute(navController: NavController) {
composable(
    route = "${Screen.Image.route}/{${ImageArgs.IMAGE_URL}}",
    arguments = listOf(
        navArgument(ImageArgs.IMAGE_URL) {
            type = NavType.StringType
        },
    )
) {
    ImageScreen(navController = navController)
  }
}
```

Happy coding! :D